# how to split a string into an array but only split on the first instance of a character (space in this case)

Tags: c#, arrays

i have a string "ABC DEF EFG" and i want to get an array:

array[0] = "ABC"
array[1] = "DEF EFG"

Comment: Adam - please tell me you didn't post this at 3.45am... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the overload:

```
"ABC DEF EFG".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2)
```

This limits the number of return parts like you want.

Comment: The given syntax is not correct. The first argument is a character array. See Eric's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Split method with a number indicating the maximum number of array elements to return:

```
"ABC DEF EFG".Split(new char[] {' '}, 2)
```

will return "ABC" and "DEF EFG"